# Is it possible to conditionally render layouts?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to change layouts in a component depending on a condition from this:

```
<template>
  <layoutA>
    //component contents
  </layoutA>
</template>
```

to this:

```
<template>
  <layoutB>
    //component contents
  </layoutB>
</template>
```

The only way I know of how to render components with a condition is with `v-if` which doesn't render child components, if the condition is not met. I could do this:

```
<template>
  <layoutA v-if="condition">
    //component contents
  </layoutA>
  <layoutB v-else>
    //component contents
  </layoutB>
</template>
```

but with large components this gets messy quickly + I would have to maintain the same code twice. It could be simplified by moving `//component contents` into its own component and import it twice. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Here's an example of a `layout`:

```
<template>
  <v-nav/>
  <slot/>
  <v-footer/>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the case for dynamic component:

```
  <componenent :is="condition ? 'layoutA' : 'layoutB'">
    //component contents
  </componenent>
```

For more complex expression it can be moved to computed property.

Comment: layoutA and layoutB  are supposed to be registered under same names in current comp. As it was said, a better way is to put this code into computed property, you can refer comps themselves and not their names there

Comment: Reminder: this works for me: `<component :is="condition ? layoutA : layoutB">` (no quotes)

Comment: Was this used with `script setup`? In this case `layoutA` var will be available in a template, I assume. It's not guaranteed to be there otherwise